# Model-Identifier for Node in JavaFX 2 TreeItem

Tags: javafx-2

Is there a way to store an identifier of a model object or the model object itself in a JavaFX 2 `TreeItem<String>`? There is just `Value` to store the text...

I'm populating a `TreeView` from a list of model objects, and need to find it when the user clicks a node. I'm used to work with `Value` and `Text` in .NET Windows Forms or HTML and I am afraid I cannot adapt this way of thinking to JavaFX...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any objects with TreeView, they just have to override `toString()` for presenting or extend `javafx.scene.Node`

E.g. for next class:

```
private static class MyObject {
    private final String value;
    public MyObject(String st) { value = st; }

    public String toString() { return "MyObject{" + "value=" + value + '}'; }
}
```

TreeView should be created next way:

```
TreeView<MyObject> treeView = new TreeView<MyObject>();
TreeItem<MyObject> treeRoot = new TreeItem<MyObject>(new MyObject("Root node"));
treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as the OP.  In addition I want to bind the value displayed in the TreeItem to a property of the object.  This isn't complete, but I'm experimenting with the following helper class, where I'm passing in the "user object" (or item) to be referenced in the TreeItem, and a valueProperty (which, in my case, is a property of the item) to be bound to the TreeItem.value.

```
final class BoundTreeItem<B, T> extends TreeItem<T> {
  public BoundTreeItem(B item, Property<T> valueProperty) {
    this(item, valueProperty, null);
  }

  public BoundTreeItem(B item, Property<T> valueProperty, Node graphic) {
    super(null, graphic);
    itemProperty.set(item);
    this.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(valueProperty);
  }

  public ObjectProperty<B> itemProperty() {
    return itemProperty;
  }

  public B getItem() {
    return itemProperty.get();
  }

  private ObjectProperty<B> itemProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
}
```

Comment: Is this answer complete? I think binding needs to be an easy option for a TreeItem's value.